# Filter ArrayList using complex AND+OR logic

Tags: java, android, arraylist, guava

I am hoping to filter an ArrayList of custom model objects down to those matching user-selected values.
The user can filter the different fields of the model object in any manner...

If they select multiple values for the same field (e.g. choosing breakfast and dinner for the "category" field) objects matching any of the selections should be returned. If they simultaneously filter using the "protein" field and choose "chicken" only chicken breakfast and dinner meals should be returned.

I am currently using Guava and Collections2.filter(...), but can't seem to combine the AND/OR logic properly.

Any guidance would be appreciated! :)

Edit: Adding code snippet as an indication that I'm not looking for "moral support"

```
Collection<FieldAcceptanceLogItem> objectFilter = allLogItems;

for (final Filter filter : mFilters) {
    objectFilter = Collections2.filter(objectFilter, new Predicate<FieldAcceptanceLogItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@javax.annotation.Nullable FieldAcceptanceLogItem input) {
            if (filter.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.sublocation))) {
                return input.getSublocation().equalsIgnoreCase(filter.getTitle());
            }
            else if (filter.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.technology))) {
                return input.getTechnology().equalsIgnoreCase(filter.getTitle());
            }
            else { //(filter.getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.component)))
                return input.getComponent().equalsIgnoreCase(filter.getTitle());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What kind of guidance are you looking for? Do you have a specific question? Some code to share with us? Or are you just looking for moral support?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Could you still explain what the code should do and what it is currently doing?

Comment: See edit. I iterate through each filter the user has applied checking to see whether a field in the FieldAcceptanceLogItem matches the title of the filter. There are three different categories for filters, hence the conditional. Applying multiple filters in the same category (the OR logic part) doesn't work... As written it expects it to match all of the filters and I'm not sure how to address that.

Comment: from a quick glance, it looks like what you're doing is filtering out everything except what matches the very first filter in `mFilters.get(0)`. In other words, if `mFilters.get(0)` had sublocation "A" and `mFilters.get(1)` had sublocation "B". By the time your second predicate kicks in, objectFilter no longer has "B" items because they were filtered out by the first predicate.

Comment: I think what you want is 3 predicates, instead of `mFilters.size()` predicates. First predicate filters out sublocations that don't match. Second filters out technologies that don't match. Third filters out components that don't match.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. That helps, but how would I filter out sublocations that don't match when their are multiple sublocation filters (e.g. Alpha, Beta)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you want the intersection of sublocation, technology, and component. I moved a couple of things around that should highlight what you're trying to tackle:

```
objectFilter = Collections2.filter(objectFilter, new Predicate<FieldAcceptanceLogItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(@javax.annotation.Nullable FieldAcceptanceLogItem input) {
        return SublocationFilters.from(mFilters).contains(input.getLocation())
        && TechnologyFilters.from(mFilters).contains(input.getTechnology())
        && ComponentFilters.from(mFilters).contains(input.getComponent());
});
```

1. `SublocationFilters.from(...)` will give you all of the sublocation filters
2. `TechnologyFilters.from(...)` will give you all of the tech filters
3. `ComponentFilters.from(...)` will give you all of the component filters
4. `contains(...)` is just a convinient method for doing "filter_1 OR filter_2 OR... filter_n"

If you do want to follow that pattern though, I'd recommend doing something more like this as it is less to write tests for:

```
new CategoryFilter(mFilters, getString(R.string.component))
    .contains(input.getComponent());
```